# Test class throwing error

Tags: unit-test, class

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray()` ? the code i have written is

```
@istest
public class StringArrayTest_Test {

    public static List<string> generateStringArray(Integer n)
    {
        List<String> myArray = new List<String>();
        n=4;
        for(Integer i=0;i<n;i++) 
        {
            myArray.add('Test'+i);
            System.debug(myArray[i]);
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

in anonymus window im giving as

```
StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray();
```

can any one help me with this

Comment: Where are you calling `StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray()` method? Please share your actual class as well.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the parameterized method. Please check it once or provide the complete code.

Answer (score 4):

**First**: Running in Anon window will yield the error

> System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context

**Second** The signature of your method is:

```
public static List<string> generateStringArray(Integer n)
```

So in order to execute it you need to pass an integer as a parameter

```
StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray(1);
```

Comment: Fastest fingers in the west!

Comment: and in the east as well. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your generateStringArray method is expecting an integer so that it knows how big of an array to generate. Try this in an anonymous window

`StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray(10);`

I think it might be as simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

Your method as defined takes an `Integer` input. You have provided none.

Change:

```
StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray();
```

To:

```
StringArrayTest_Test.generateStringArray(0);
```

(or any other Integer value);

Comment: third fastest fingers in the west! :)

Comment: This time. Haha. You can tell which of us has the sportsmanship badge already. :)